# Jtextarea error, won't display result

Tags: java

I have a problem with my JTextArea. I'm new at programming. I want to outoput all the passed and failed grades on the jtextarea. there is no error when build but when i run the program there is a long message that shows like an error in the dialog box and the grades didn't output.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    String a;
    String output = "Passed\tFailed";
    int array [] = new int [20];
    int passed = 0, failed = 0;

    JTextArea outputA = new JTextArea();

    for (int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++) {
        a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student " + (counter + 1) + " Score: ");
        array[counter] = Integer.parseInt(a);
    }

    for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < array.length ; counter1++) {
        if (array[counter1] >= 75) {
            passed += 1;
            output += array[counter1] + "\t";
        }
        else  {
            failed += 1;
            output += array[counter1] + "\n";
        }
    }

    outputA.setText(output);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(  null, 
                                    outputA + "\n" + 
                                    "Number of students who passed: " + passed + "\n" + 
                                    "Number of students who failed: " + failed);
}
```

Comment: What does the long message say exactly?

Comment: *there is a long message that shows like an error*: seriously, have you thought about *reading* it?

Comment: its long but it's like this javax.swing.JTextArea[,0,0,0x0 invalid, layout = javax.swing......

Comment: Do you see the word "Exception" in it, especially near the top?  With a line number?  Can you show us the code from the line(s) it references?

Comment: Also, read a Swing tutorial. Your code makes no sense. A JTextArea must be placed into a JFrame or a JDialog, and this top-level component must be made visible. You can't just use a JTextArea alone. And concatenating a JTextArea with a String and displaying this String in a JOptionPane is not how you make a JTextArea visible on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You put outputA in the message as Text. `outputA` is a JTextArea. So you put `textArea.toString()` as message in the `JOptionPane` and thats what you see.

put `outputA.getText()` as message in the `JOptionPane`

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputA.getText() + "\n" + "Number of students who passed: " + passed +
                                    "\n" + "Number of students who failed: " + failed);
```

Or simple add `output` as message to the pane

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output + "\n" + "Number of students who passed: " + passed +
                                    "\n" + "Number of students who failed: " + failed);
```